# Can I use discord.js in React-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, discord

I want to use discord login in React-native. So i found ' discord.js ' then I install with npm into my project directory.

But the errors occurs that

> bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `os` from
>   `C:\react-native-workspace\discordTest4\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Constants.js`:
>   Module does not exist in the module map

What's the problem? The reason is that I can't use Javascript Libraries in React-native?

If its true, Please tell me the way to login in react-native.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Unfortuantely.. React Native doesn't ship with a bundled Node.js.. hence you cannot use any modules from the Node.js API

Comment: Found a way to use Node.js in React Native..  try checking this out.. https://github.com/staltz/react-native-node

Comment: ok I see.. Using Node.js in RN can make some performance issue?

Comment: It might since you're running it in the background.. but it wont be too much too notice

Comment: Ok.. I need to  consider that way :)

Comment: did you manage how to use discord api in react native app?